# Is it UB to modify a const object's member via its non-const reference?

Tags: c++

```cpp
class T {
public:
    int v;
    int &vRef;
public:
    T() : v(0), vRef(v) {}
};

const T t; // note, it's a const object
t.vRef = 2;
printf("v: %d\n", t.v);
```

The code presented above compiles OK, and the const object's internal value did change.

**Question.** Is this Undefined Behavior or not?

Comment: Yes and it makes sense too. On some processor architectures a const variable could be put into some unmodifiable piece of RAM (with readonly rights) or even ROM.

Comment: Yes.   Modifying a non-`mutable` member of a `const` object by any means gives undefined behaviour.   If you really want to modify a member of a `const` object without undefined behaviour, then make it `mutable`.   In your case, that means `v` should be `mutable` and you have no need for `vRef`.

Comment: Worth noting that an object under construction (before the constructor of the most derived object ends) is not const yet (https://eel.is/c++draft/class#ctor.general-5) so you can modify `v` and `vRef` inside the body of the constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. If the object is declared as `const`, then modifying it (through *any* means, be that a non-const reference like in your example, via `const_cast` or something else) is [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: So why does this compile?

Comment: @PaulSanders In the same way you initialize any `const` classes: they aren't `const` until the constructor finishes.

Comment: @PasserBy I'm talking about `t.vRef = 2;`

Comment: @PaulSanders Because the `const` qualifies the reference, not the `int`, and that does nothing, `t.vRef` is still a `int&`.

Comment: @PasserBy Right, got it.  So `t.vRef = 2;` is perfectly fine then, no UB here (because we're not modifying `t`).

Comment: @PaulSanders I can't tell what it is you're asking. `t.vRef` has type `int&`, its referee is a `const int`, modifying a `const int` through whatever means is UB. This is one of the cases where the type system doesn't protect you from UB.

Comment: @PasserBy What I'm saying is, I'm not convinced that `t.vRef = 2` is UB.  While `t` is `const`, `t.vRef` is not, or that's the way I see it, at least.

Comment: @PasserBy Sorry, I should have said that what `t.vRef` is _referring_ to is not `const`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255987/discussion-between-passer-by-and-paul-sanders).

Comment: @PasserBy Ah, forget it, I see it now.  `vRef` is referring to a `const` variable, sorry about the noise.

Comment: Jesper Juhl, "modifying it" is more like "attempting to modifying it".

Comment: @PaulSanders "So why does this compile?" - Because the compiler is not required to diagnose UB. It's on *you* to avoid it.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I don't think that adds anything, to be honest.  I already know that, and Passer By was kind enough to explain things for me.